# Opening Accordion from external link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found some code that might work, but I can't decipher how to change it so it works with my current accordion structure.

Here is the fix I had found:

```
$(function () {
$(".tab-content").hide().first().show();
$(".inner-nav li:first").addClass("active");

$(".inner-nav a").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('li').addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    $($(this).attr('href')).show().siblings('.tab-content').hide();
});

var hash = $.trim( window.location.hash );

if (hash) $('.inner-nav a[href$="'+hash+'"]').trigger('click');

});
```

and Here is part of the accordion on my page:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="accordion-trigger">
<h3>Wedding</h3>
</div>
<div class="accordion-container">
<p>
<tab>
<bgcolor class="shadow">
<a href="pdf/MyLifestyle_WeddingPackages_020616_01.pdf"><font color="black" size="+1"><strong>Wedding Packages PDF</strong></font></a>
</bgcolor>
</tab>
</p>
<hr class="separator1"> 
</div>
```

Inside the div container are several other div class="accordion-trigger"'s that get activated when you click. Of course, only the first accordion is active on the page on load.

The fix above is supposed to check for a hash ID and do a Click event on the hash id.

Comment: How do you identify your active tab? By order? What is expected correct hash?

Comment: When it's clicked on, it becomes active via CSS (I believe) as DW dictates .active on the active "accordion-trigger".

Comment: Wasn't sure if I could give each accordion trigger it's own ID

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using CSS you haven't provided, to open navigation:

```
$(function () {
    var hash = parseInt($.trim(window.location.hash)), // hash as number
        $triggers = $('.accordion-trigger'); // list of triggers
    if (hash) { // if hash exists
        if($triggers.length >= hash) { // if not greater than number of triggers
            $triggers.eq(hash+1).trigger('click'); // open n-th item
        }
    }
});
```

`example.com/site/#4` should open 4th item, if it exists.
That's terrible code, by the way.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, I will definitely be trying it out. Will let you know how it pans out.

Comment: Which code is terrible, by the way? Asking for learning purposes.

Comment: If you have more than one entity of this module on the page, it will not work. It's unscalable. If you are using CSS, consider using it also for opening proper tab on load, ex. by adding hash as class to body element by JavaScript. Mixing it is bad practice.